# Insert data in SQLite for JavaFX Applications

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this class below called **Database** to facilitate the manipulation of my sqlite database:

```
public class Database {

    private String conString = "jdbc:sqlite:database.db";
    private Connection con = null;

    public Database() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(conString);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
            con = null;
        }
        return con;
    }

    public void initTables() {
        try {
            Statement st = getConnection().createStatement();
            st.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS setting(name TEXT, value TEXT)");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
        }
    }

    // ################################################################################
    // # SETTING TABLE
    // ################################################################################

    public List<Setting> getSettings() {
        List<Setting> result = new ArrayList<Setting>();
        try {
            Statement st = getConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet r = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM setting");
            while (r.next()) {
                result.add(new Setting(r.getString("name"), r
                        .getString("value")));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
            result = new ArrayList<Setting>();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void createSetting(Setting s) {
        try {
            Statement st = getConnection().createStatement();
            st.execute("INSERT INTO setting (name,value) VALUES(" + s.getName()
                    + "," + s.getValue() + ")");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
        }
    }

    public void updateSetting(Setting s) {
        try {
            Statement st = getConnection().createStatement();
            st.execute("UPDATE setting SET value = " + s.getValue()
                    + " WHERE name = " + s.getName());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
        }
    }

    public Setting findSetting(String name) {
        Setting setting = null;
        try {
            Statement st = getConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st
                    .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM setting WHERE name = " + name);
            while (rs.next()) {
                setting = new Setting(rs.getString("name"),
                        rs.getString("value"));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
            setting = null;
        }
        return setting;
    }
}
```

After invoking `createSetting` method, an error was thrown:

```
    Jul 21, 2015 3:26:49 PM com.database.Database createSetting
    SEVERE: null
    java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: fname)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:901)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:868)
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:211)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:60)
        at com.rameses.database.Database.createSetting(Database.java:68)
        at com.rameses.sample.DatabaseSample$1.handle(DatabaseSample.java:35)
        at com.rameses.sample.DatabaseSample$1.handle(DatabaseSample.java:31)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$217/1740853902.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/485815673.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The actual invocation process is something like this:

```
save.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Database db = new Database();
        db.createSetting(new Setting(name.getText(),value.getText()));
    }
});
```

**QUESTION :** Where do you think is the error and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the values in your query in quotes.

So the query :

```
st.execute("INSERT INTO setting (name,value) VALUES(" + s.getName()
                + "," + s.getValue() + ")");
```

should be :

```
st.execute("INSERT INTO setting (name,value) VALUES('" + s.getName()
                + "','" + s.getValue() + "')");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
        st.execute("INSERT INTO setting (name,value) VALUES(" + s.getName()
                + "," + s.getValue() + ")");
```

The reason is that the values to be inserted are not escaped correctly (in fact not escaped at all). The naive solution (just to demonstrate the flaw) is to enclose the values in single quotes. Of course, **THIS LEAVES YOU OPEN TO POTENTIAL SQL INJECTION PROBLEMS**!

```
        st.execute("INSERT INTO setting (name,value) VALUES('" + s.getName()
        // HERE --------------------------------------------^
                + "','" + s.getValue() + "')");
        // HERE ---^-^--------------------^
```

To avoid the SQL injection problem, use `PreparedStatement`s:

```
PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO setting (name,value) VALUES(?,?)");
ps.setString(1, s.getName());
ps.setString(2, s.getValue());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

(You will also need to properly close the statements and -especially- connections in `final` clauses.)